# Django -- Aggregates Sums in postgreSQL don't use DISTINCT. Is this a bug?

Tags: django

Is this a bug? I'm not good at SQL, but it looks like the aggregate function doesn't respect the distinct() passed to the queryset.

```
distinct_queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(reverse_relationship__icontains='foo').distinct()

iterated_total = 0
for item in distinct_queryset:
    iterated_total += item.total

aggregate = queryset.aggregate(Sum('total'))
```

`aggregate is Decimal('42201.20')`

`iterated_total is Decimal('38212.20')`

`aggregate is not total`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

I finally tested it with debug=true and connections.queries.

on `somequery.distinct()` I get:
`'sql': 'SELECT DISTINCT ............ WHERE....LIKE FOO`

on aggregate of a distinct queryset I get:
`'sql': 'SELECT .......... WHERE...LIKE FOO`

After searching google, I did find http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/87cc286019c7d57c

> I managed in this way:
>
> subquery =
>   Father.objects.filter(sons_in=[adam,
>   bernard])
>   Father.objects.filter(pk_in=subquery).aggregate(Sum('age'))

This gives the correct result. Is there a better way to do so? (maybe more efficient?)

I will keep adding via python from my gut feeling.

Comment: Wow thanks! It's not related to postgres, happens in mysql too.